# PHP check if array key exist

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a array and within that array i have more elements. I want to check if a specific element exist

```
  $jsondata = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $jsonobj = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

## Possibility 1

```
$jsonobj=Array(
      [user] => Array
            (
              [userId] => 1501148600220
              [locale] => en-US
                // no TOKEN
            )
);
```

## Possibility 2

```
$jsonobj=Array(
          [user] => Array
                (
                  [userId] => 1501148600220
                  [locale] => en-US
                  [token] => 12345    // TOKEN exist
                )
               );
```

The follwing is a decoded JSON. 
The Received JSON sometimes **might** and **might not** contain the element 'token'.

I want to check if the $jsonobj has the element 'token'

```
    if (array_key_exists('token', $jsonobj)) {
    echo "Element is in the array";
    }
```

How do i check this according to the structure of my array?

## UPDATE

Sometimes, the jsonobj might not contain anything. It could be empty. If it is empty i get an error

```
PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array
```

Comment: Well, you obviously decode the JSON _string_ to have an object or array and then check if that element or property exists. What is the question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass the index **'user'** in the multidimensional `$jsonobj` array

Like this

```
if (array_key_exists('token', $jsonobj['user'])) {
  echo "Element is in the array";
 }
```

Modified:-

```
$jsonobj=json_decode($jsonobj,true);
if(!empty($jsonobj['user'])&&is_array($jsonobj['user']))
{
    if (array_key_exists('token', $jsonobj['user'])) {
        echo "Element is in the array";
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error, PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array

Comment: Try the modified answer

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (array_key_exists('token', $jsonobj['user'])) {
  echo "Element is in the array";
 }
```

Comment: I get an error, PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array

Comment: Yes. It was the empty array case. Just saw that someone sorted that out. Nice

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your `$jsonobj` array key that is `user`.
So, if you want to check `user` array key then you should write like this,

```
if (array_key_exists('token', $jsonobj['user'])) 
{
  echo "Element is in the array";
}
```

See this [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($jsonobj as $obj => $val){
    if(is_array($val)){     
        if(array_key_exists('token', $val)){
            echo 'exist';
        }else{
            echo 'not exist';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use this one liner to check if nested key exists in array:

```php
Arr::has($jsonobj, 'user.token');
// Or
Arr::has($jsonobj, ['user', 'token']);
```

If you want to learn more about this method or other methods useful when dealing with multidimensional arrays check out this [php array library](https://packagist.org/packages/minwork/array)