# Find entry in JSON (Kraken.com uncommon JSON format)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to find if a string exists in JSON Kraken.com retrieved file:
I get it this way:

```
$sURL = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=ETHAED&interval=5&since=". strtotime("-1 day");

$ch = curl_init();

$config['useragent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['useragent']);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sURL);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result, true);
```

Sometimes pairs names differ from URL string and JSON (i.e. I can write LTCEUR but in JSON I see LTCZEUR

So I need to check if the string **does exists** in the `$obj`

```
$sName = "ETHAED";

print_r($obj);

if (in_array($sName,$obj)){

    echo("Found ".$sName."<br>");

}else{

    echo("NOT FOUND"."<br>");

}
```

but this doesn't work.

if I do a print_r() I can clearly see the pair name, but can't verify it.
Any suggestion?

Kraken.com JSON is not standard so I can't easily retrieve the name of the PAIR, I tried all possible combinations of $obj["result"][$sName] but without result.

Example:
https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=LTCUSD
Here pair is **LTCUSD**

But on Json:

`{"error":[],"result":{"XLTCZUSD":[[1669197540,"78.74","78.74","78.58","78.59","78.59","23.82168114",8]`

Comment: We don't actually need to see any of your curl code.  We only need to see your input array (`$obj`) to resolve this question.  Topical: [PHP check if array key exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45347897/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your comparison.

```php
in_array($sName,$obj)
```

Should be:

```php
is_array($obj['result'][$sName] ?? null)
```

**Caveat:** Read that carefully; it's now `is` instead of `in`.

Or, if you don't care if it's `null`, a string, or non-array:

```php
array_key_exists($obj['result'], $sName)
```

### Detailed explanation

`in_array($sName,$obj)` is checking if `$sName` matches (`==` equality) any of the elements in the first level of your array.

Since the first level of the array looks like this (pseudocode here):

```
error => []
result => [
    XLTCZUSD => [...]
    last: 123456
]
```

Since `'ETHAED'` is neither `[]` nor is it `[XLTCZUSD => [...],last: 123456]` it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works perfectly.
Just a little correction on format:

```
if (array_key_exists($sName, $obj['result'])){
echo("FOUND ".$sName."<br>");           
}else{
echo("ERROR ".$sName."<br>"); 
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to `echo` an array?